# Compute how many samples have been improved, according to a minimum threshold or confidence interval, in a given set in comparison to another set?

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, difference

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID      VAL1    VAL2
Q2241   0.3333  0.3353
Q2242   0.5     0.5
Q2243   0.3333  0.3333
Q2244   0.2137  0.4792
Q2245   0.1429  0.2
Q2246   0.5     0.5
Q2247   0.4167  0.6667
Q2248   1       1
Q2249   0.125   0.0909
Q2250   0.2     0.2
Q2251   0.325   0.2667
Q2252   0.1667  0.2
Q2253   0.3333  0.25
Q2254   0.45    0.8333
Q2255   0.3333  0.5
Q2256   1       1
Q2257   0.5     0.51
Q2258   0.3929  0.3333
Q2259   0.3611  0.625
```

Is there a way to correctly compute the number of samples (`ID`) where `VAL2` is significantly higher/lower than `VAL1` in a given dataframe.
I'm looking for something like [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test), where a measure gives results like the following example:

```
Win Tie Loss        
64  36  137
```

where:

> ```
> Win: number of IDs where VAL2 is higher than VAL1 with some confidence interval  
> Tie: number of IDs where VAL2 ~ VAL1 (no significant difference, 0.0001 for example) 
> Loss: number of IDs where VAL2 is lower than VAL1 with some confidence interval
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tol = 0.0001
win = (df.VAL2 > (df.VAL1 + tol)).sum()
loss = (df.VAL2 < (df.VAL1 - tol)).sum()
tie = ((df.VAL1 - df.VAL2).abs() <= tol).sum()

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Win': win, 'Tie':tie, 'Loss': loss}])
print (df)
#    Loss  Tie  Win
# 0     4    6    9
```

Comment: Thanks @Ghilas BELHADJ I already tried something like that, but I was wondering if there is some specific method in data science that enable to do such a statistic, some official function like "t-test" ?

Comment: There is a list of [Software implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Software_implementations) in the bottom of your Wikipedia page. So basically, you can use [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) in Python.

Comment: The t-test evaluates the significance of the differences between 2 distributions but does not give how many samples that are significantly different. One better solution will combine the significance probability given by the t-test with something else to compute the number of these samples. Do you think that computing the t-test value for each line in my data frame will make sense?

Comment: Probably not. but I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll discuss that with my advisors then leave a comment here.